# Odoo : manufacture many products from one product

Tags: odoo

Can Odoo handle manufacturing of many products from one raw material product such as 1 chicken is processed to produce 8 or more products such as half, quarter portions , drumsticks etc

Answer (score 0):

Sure, you can have this configured in odoo.
For Every finished product you need to create bom in which you can use same product chicken as a row. You can set Byproduct if any produced during your process.